# Modifiy Json File with Key Values

Tags: python, json

Hello i need to modify json file with the key values of outcomeType>displayName. My code only shows one key value of displayName; however need to create 2 key with key values.

Json:

```
{ "18916": [ { "id": 2275920175, "eventId": 16, "minute": 0, "second": 51, "teamId": 223, "playerId": 18916, "x": 66.6, "y": 81.2, "expandedMinute": 0, "period": { "value": 1, "displayName": "FirstHalf" }, "type": { "value": 1, "displayName": "Pass" }, "outcomeType": { "value": 1, "displayName": "Successful" }, "qualifiers": [ { "type": { "value": 213, "displayName": "Angle" }, "value": "2.8" }, { "type": { "value": 56, "displayName": "Zone" }, "value": "Left" }, { "type": { "value": 212, "displayName": "Length" }, "value": "12.4" }, { "type": { "value": 140, "displayName": "PassEndX" }, "value": "55.3" }, { "type": { "value": 141, "displayName": "PassEndY" }, "value": "86.6" } ], "satisfiedEventsTypes": [ 90, 118, 116, 29, 34, 36, 215, 217 ], "isTouch": true, "endX": 55.3, "endY": 86.6 }, { "id": 2275920577, "eventId": 29, "minute": 1, "second": 24, "teamId": 223, "playerId": 18916, "x": 75, "y": 80.2, "expandedMinute": 1, "period": { "value": 1, "displayName": "FirstHalf" }, "type": { "value": 1, "displayName": "Pass" }, "outcomeType": { "value": 1, "displayName": "Successful" }, "qualifiers": [ { "type": { "value": 212, "displayName": "Length" }, "value": "22.1" }, { "type": { "value": 141, "displayName": "PassEndY" }, "value": "76.4" }, { "type": { "value": 56, "displayName": "Zone" }, "value": "Center" }, { "type": { "value": 213, "displayName": "Angle" }, "value": "6.2" }, { "type": { "value": 140, "displayName": "PassEndX" }, "value": "95.9" } ], "satisfiedEventsTypes": [ 90, 118, 116, 29, 204, 35, 37, 216, 217 ], "isTouch": true, "endX": 95.9, "endY": 76.4 }, { "id": 2275921705, "eventId": 49, "minute": 3, "second": 11, "teamId": 223, "playerId": 18916, "x": 73.5, "y": 79.7, "expandedMinute": 3, "period": { "value": 1, "displayName": "FirstHalf" }, "type": { "value": 1, "displayName": "Pass" }, "outcomeType": { "value": 0, "displayName": "Unsuccessful" }, "qualifiers": [ { "type": { "value": 56, "displayName": "Zone" }, "value": "Center" }, { "type": { "value": 3, "displayName": "HeadPass" } }, { "type": { "value": 212, "displayName": "Length" }, "value": "19.1" }, { "type": { "value": 140, "displayName": "PassEndX" }, "value": "89.7" }, { "type": { "value": 213, "displayName": "Angle" }, "value": "5.8" }, { "type": { "value": 141, "displayName": "PassEndY" }, "value": "66.9" } ], "satisfiedEventsTypes": [ 90, 119, 28, 138, 35, 37, 216, 217 ], "isTouch": true, "endX": 89.7, "endY": 66.9 }]}
```

Code:

```
    for js in data_passes[18916]:
    icdType = js["outcomeType"]["displayName"]
    if icdType in pass_type:
        pass_type[icdType].append(js)
    else:
        pass_type[icdType] = [js]

data_pass_type = json.dumps(pass_type)
data_pass_type = json.loads(data_pass_type)    

with open('test.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data_pass_type, json_file)
```

Result:

[Result Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASUTM.png)

Expected Result: Both Successful and UnSuccessful key values. (UnSuccessful missing)

Comment: Your code works for me.  I get 2 Successful and 1 Unsuccessful from your sample data.  However, I will note that where you have `data_passes[18916]`, it should be `data_passes["18916"]`.  It is a string value, not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, after changing the integer to a string:

```
import json

data_passes = json.load(open("x.txt"))
pass_type = {}
for js in data_passes["18916"]:
    icdType = js["outcomeType"]["displayName"]
    if icdType in pass_type:
        pass_type[icdType].append(js)
    else:
        pass_type[icdType] = [js]

with open('test.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(pass_type, json_file)
```

Result:

```
{
  "Successful": [
    {
      "id": 2275920175,
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 2275920577,
      ...
    }
  ],
  "Unsuccessful": [
    {
      "id": 2275921705,
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. "18916" is a variable actually, i noticed that some of these ids does not have both.